# What's wrong with this R function?

Tags: r

I want to define a simple function that will filter a data frame, similar to something you might do in SPSS with the "Select Cases" menu option.

Here is what I would type in the console to filter it using the subset function if I wanted to only keep cases where q3a is 1: `subset(df, q3a==1)`. This will run with no problem and returns a data frame including only those cases where q3a is 1.

However, when I use the following function, I get an error:

```
filter <- function(frame, var, val) {
    newFrame <- subset(frame, var==val)
    return(newFrame)
}
```

When I try to run `filter(df, q3a, 1)`, R throws me the following error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'q3a' not found`.

I can't see what the problem is here. It seems like the function should just directly pass the arguments to the subset function, but clearly that's not happening.

Comment: just for interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: Are you aware of the function [`filter`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) from `dplyr` which does what you want? It's advisable to use functions from established packages where possible.

Comment: `filter(df, df$q3a, 1)`.

Comment: @user20650 Thanks! I will use indices from now on.

Comment: @Hugh, I was not aware, thank you for the information. However, I was using this more as a learning example so I am still interested in understanding why the function I wrote wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Most built-in R functions will take an unquoted argument like `q3a` and make it behave like a string.

To achieve the same functionality, try this:

```
filter <- function(frame, var, val) {
    return(frame[eval(substitute(var), frame)==val, ])
}
```

Notice I'm using a different approach rather than `subset`, which uses non-standard evaluation [and can make things very complicated](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#calling-from-another-function).